# How to get only numbers from last parentheses?

Tags: php

I need help with getting number from last parentheses in one string. My code take all number from string.

This is my code:

```
$string = "Mixing group (3pcs) (350) ";
echo (int)preg_replace('/(\D)/', '', $string);
```

This gives me result : 3350.

But result need to be only number from last parentheses: 350.

Comment: Can there be letters inside the last parentheses as well? Or just digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex to search for digits in parentheses, using a negative lookahead to assert that there are no more parentheses after that number:

```
$string = "Mixing group (3pcs) (350) ";

preg_match('/\((\d+)\)(?!.*\(.*\))/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

```
350
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/t2cVC)